# Qt: QOpenGLContexts "mix" with differnt widgets

Tags: qt, opengl

I am recently building a Qt application with native openGL streaming data in the Qt window.

I have 2 widgets inherited from QOpenGLWidget, one has parent, the other doesn't have a parent. They both work well individually (just show() one widget per time). However, when I try to render them simultaneously, one of the texture I bind via glBindTexture() appears in the wrong window. It's like they are using the same context(). But by inheriting from QOpenGLWidget, they should have two different context.

In my code, I just override initializeGL, paintGL and resizeGL as usual

```
void initializeGL(){
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    // generate buffer, allocation, shaders...
}
void paintGL(){
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // bind vao, bind texture, drawElements...
}
```

Basically, my second window(window2) is a "video player" plays the image sequence from memory. But it appears on the window1. I have also set a QSurfaceFormat by:

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);
format.setVersion(3,3);
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
setFormat(format);
```

in the constructor.
Could someone tell me what might be wrong here? I think the context() the two windows use are different, then how could I glBindTexture in window2 could apply for window1? If you found these information are not enough, please tell me, Thanks.

platform: Ubuntu16.04, Qt5.6.2, OpenGL3.3

### Update:

I have the same issue with this post: [OpenGL multiple window rendering](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/177261-OPENGL-MUTILPLE-WINDOW-RENDERING). However, mine is inside Qt5 environment, theoretically, it should works.